# Google Rejects a JWT - NodeJS & jsonwebtoken

Tags: node.js, google-api, json-web-token

The thing is that I want to periodically (twice a week) ask google for **reviews of apps** in a *Google Developer account*.

I want to store them automatically in a database that I have in a **NodeJS Server**, and what I do is make an *HTTPS* request to google, following their instructions from [Google's OAuth2.0 docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Always I get this response, the token seems to be badly signed (I'm messing something up with the signature, but don't know what):

```
{

    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature.",
    "error_uri": ""

}
```

#### What I do

I use the plugin of **jsonwebtoken** found [here in GitHub](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken). Then, I sign it with:

```
let signed = jwt.sign( payload, secure.getPrivateKey(), { algorithm: 'RS256'} );
```

And finally I append the signature at the end of the payload, wich results in something similar to:

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJvYmZ1c2NhdGVkIGZvciBvYmlvdXMgcmVhc29ucyA6KSIsInNjb3BlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vYXV0aC9kZXZzdG9yYWdlLnJlYWRvbmx5IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vb2F1dGgyL3Y0L3Rva2VuIiwiZXhwIjoxNDc2ODkxMjU5LCJpYXQiOjE0NzY4ODc2NTl9

You can checkout [JWT.io here](https://jwt.io/) to see the payload composition.

#### The Data

All fields are extracted from **keys.json** a file that google did give me from the developer console when I created the project some days ago.

The **iss field** is taken from the field **"client_email"**, wich *ends with .iam.gserviceaccount.com*

The **secure.getPrivateKey()** gets the info from the field **"private_key"**.

So if anyone has experience with google OAuth using **server to server** auth, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Probably not the reason, but when you say *it results in something similar* you mean that the token you're sending will actually have the signature component, right? The example token you added just has header and payload, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Exactly! I have not posted the signature and the field "iss" is obfuscated. So you have here only header & payload, but I send all together to google